# Calculating SSE in R

Tags: r, sums-of-squares

I'm following the "Intro to Statistics" course in Data Camp and I'm having some trouble as it seems that the course is contradicting itself: https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/production/course_1799/slides/ch5.pdf

Slide 5 says SSE = (.resid^2)
Same in slide 15, 16

However, when doing an exercise they suggest and only take as valid answer:

```
mod_null %>%
summarize(SSE = var(.resid))
```

I'm confused right now and I'll really appreciate if someone could show me the right direction

Comment: Under the assumption that the residuals have mean 0, the SSE is almost nearly the variance of the residuals.  If the course is contracting itself, that is a pedagogical error, not a statistical one.

Comment: Isn't the mean of the residuals ALWAYS ~0?

Comment: No, it would depend on the data.  If you use a linear model for a phenomena which is non-linear, there is no guarantee MRSE is approx 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If residuals are differences between true $y_i$ and predicted values $\hat{y}_i$, i.e. $r_i = y_i - \hat{y}_i$. SEE stands for *sum of squared errors* (also known as *[residual sum of squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_sum_of_squares)*, RSS), so it is defined as $\text{SSE} = \sum_{i=1}^n r^2$. [*Mean squared error*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) is the mean of residuals, so $\frac{1}{n} \text{SSE}$. The exercise you mention seems to accept as answer variance of residuals (errors), i.e. $\frac{1}{n-1} \text{SSE}$, people often use it to calculate [coefficient of determination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) $R^2$ using the build-in functions for variance $1 - \frac{\text{Var}(Y-\hat{Y})}{\text{Var}(Y)}$, instead of the usual formula $1 - \frac{\text{SSE}}{\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \bar y)^2}$, since they are equivalent.

Obviously the three measures are not the same, and the course seems to be confusing them. They are different just by constants, so it wouldn't matter much if you are just minimizing them (e.g. minimizing squared errors in linear regression), or when using mean (or sum) squared error to compare different models using same dataset (so with same $n$).